# Why is this OSX/BSD/GNU sed workaround not working

Tags: bash

So sed behaves differently depending on if it is the OSX/BSD or GNU version.

OSX requires

```
sed -i '' <pattern> <file>
```

whereas this works with GNU sed:

```
sed -i <pattern> <file>
```

So I have this:

```
darwin=false;
case "$(uname)" in
    Darwin*) darwin=true ;;
esac

if $darwin; then
    sedi="sed -i '' "
else
    sedi="sed -i"
fi
```

And then I try to call it on OSX

```
$sedi "s/VERSION =.*;/VERSION = \"${lver}\";/g" Version.java
```

And it works except for it creates a backup file named Version.java''.

I'm not sure why this isn't working because if I do it explicitly from the CLI:

```
sed -i '' "s/VERSION =.*;/VERSION = \"${lver}\";/g" Version.java
```

It works without creating the backup file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So I passed -x to bash and I see this is what is getting executed: `sed -i ''\'''\'''`

Comment: use perl inline editin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you expand your `sedi` variable, what is happening is that the `''` is passed to `sed` as an argument, rather that creating an empty argument as expected.

The best way I can see around this is to make your `sedi` variable an array:

```
if $darwin; then
    sedi=(sed -i '')
else
    sedi=(sed -i)
fi
```

And use like this:

```
"${sedi[@]}" "s/VERSION =.*;/VERSION = \"${lver}\";/g" Version.java
```

Otherwise, I think the only way to turn your `''` into an actual empty argument is to use `eval` with your original declaration:

```
eval $sedi '"s/VERSION =.*;/VERSION = \"${lver}\";/g"' Version.java
```

However this is a somewhat nasty solution since you have to add an extra layer of quotes/escapes to the rest of the command. Also it is generally good (and secure) practice to avoid using `eval` where possible.

#### Update

As commented below, creating a function will work. On the same track, an `alias` is probably the shortest method:

```
if $darwin; then
    alias sedi="sed -i ''"
else
    alias sedi="sed -i"
fi
```

Making the usage simply:

```
sedi "s/VERSION =.*;/VERSION = \"${lver}\";/g" Version.java
```

Comment: Or `if "$darwin"; then sedi() { sed -i '' "$@"; }...`

Answer (score 1):

Define a shell function that wraps `sed` instead:

```
case "$(uname)" in
    Darwin*) sed () { command sed -i '' "$@"; } ;;
    *)       sed () { command sed -i "$@"; } ;;
esac
```